# All p-values of linear mixed models equal to 0

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, p-value, residuals, linear

I am trying to model a varible (maximum depth) in function of type of dive and diel changes (day,night) with the individuals (whales in this case) as random factor in R.

I tried to apply a linear mixed model and in the output all p-values were equal to 0. Is this normal?

My residuals seem to be highly correlated and not normal, maybe this is the reason?

```
> summary(model_3)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  27045.81 27087.04 -13515.91

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | whale
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    23.89776  37.4838

Fixed effects: max_depths ~ dive_type + diel_1 
                Value Std.Error   DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)  73.78683  6.583953 2650  11.207072       0
dive_typeNF -20.89583  1.504706 2650 -13.886982       0
diel_1Day    15.32117  3.968288 2650   3.860902       0
diel_1Dusk  -30.19476  4.482896 2650  -6.735548       0
diel_1Night -36.36322  4.037502 2650  -9.006365       0
 Correlation: 
            (Intr) dv_tNF dl_1Dy dl_1Ds
dive_typeNF -0.123                     
diel_1Day   -0.576  0.009              
diel_1Dusk  -0.477 -0.069  0.802       
diel_1Night -0.527 -0.007  0.875  0.781

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.72405178 -0.55590897 -0.06697996  0.42508408  6.76001567 

Number of Observations: 2675
Number of Groups: 21
```

Also, when I try to apply a GLM with Poisson or negative binomial distribution my residuals continue to be autocorrelated and/or not normal. What model should I try after which could fit better?

Answer (score 4):

In general *p*-values are not equal to zero, but are just very very tiny, so statistical software tends to report `0` or `0.000` instead of a number like `0.0000000000183` (I tend to report such like so: "*p* <0.001").

Given that your sample size is in the thousands, and that **in your specific case** you have (fixed effect) coefficients with *t* test statistics that are all about 4 or higher, it is expected that that your *p* values will all be quite small.

Notice, however, that some of your random effects are smallish (i.e., 0.007), and were your to obtain the test statistics for these terms, they might or might not have tiny *p* values.

Autocorrelation certainly may be affecting the validity of your SEs, and therefore your *p* values and CIs.

It is difficult to say *which* model is correct for you without knowing more, but you might find the Poisson autoregression model discussed in Foikanos, K., Rahbek, A., & Tjøstheim, D. (n.d.). Poisson Autoregression. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 104(488), 1430–1439 to be enlightening.

Comment: @CatarinaToscano does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer.